# Reverse Proxy Using "Nginx-Proxy-Manager"

Tags: docker, nginx, devops, reverse-proxy, portainer

I have two servers. One is on 192.168.1.A and the other is on 192.168.1.B.

I want to set up 'nginx-proxy-manager' using Docker on 192.168.1.A and create a reverse-proxy to a git server serving from port '192.168.1.B:5000' when accessing '192.168.1.A/git'.

Additionally, I aim to set up a reverse-proxy to port '192.168.1.B:5001' when accessing '192.168.1.A/paperless'.

In other words, I want to connect to the git container when 'test.example.com/git' is entered and to the paperless container when 'test.example.com/paperless' is entered along with the domain name. How can I achieve this?

Also, can I view and manage the containers on these two servers through a single 'Portainer container'?